# How to stop a redirect?

Tags: php, html, redirect, submit

I have 2 forms. one sumbit is just an submit/add and the second is select/redirect. right now both are redirecting. How can I prevent the top submit from redirecting following?

```
<?php
if($_POST){

        //store as session variable
        $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['bolredir'];
        //forward browser
        die(header("Location: add-job.php"));
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

        <body>
       <div class="">
                <form name="addcust" method="post" action="index.php">
                        <label> Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="cust_name" name="cust_name"/> <br />
                        <input type ="submit" name="addcust" value="Submit" /> <br /> <br />
                </form>
        </div>

   <?php

 try
     {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer");
     $stmt->execute();

     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
 ?>
 <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
 <select name="bolredir">
 <option></option>
 <?php
     foreach ($result as $row)
         {
         echo "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['cust_name']}</option>";
        //$_SESSION['id'] = $row['cust_name'];
         }
     }
 ?>
 </select>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: By redirect what do you mean? to another page? I cant see any code for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the second form's submit a different name

```
<input type="submit" name="SubmitForRedirect" value="Submit" />
```

Now in your php use this code

```
if(isset($_POST['SubmitForRedirect'])) {
    //store as session variable
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['bolredir'];
    //forward browser
    die(header("Location: add-job.php"));
}
```

You can also have the second form redirect directly to add-job.php

replace `<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` by `add-job.php`

```
<form action="add-job.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: I probably should of posted my session code as well. the use of isset totally borks my session data. I updated the code to reflect the session information.

Comment: isset to work properly, you have to give the html submit button name as specified

Comment: Let me know if you still have any issue

Comment: Works like a champ! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could return false on the form submission. Give the 2nd form a name such as, "dontsubmit", and then stop it from submitting and causing the form redirection.

```
document.forms["dontsubmit"].onsubmit = function(){
   return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the use in that, if the form is not submitted :)

Comment: @SajithNair What'cha mean?

Comment: I mean if the form is not for submitting, then why do he have a submit button?

Comment: the other page it redirects to (add-job.php) is just    <?php
require_once("header2.php");
echo $_SESSION['id'];
?>

Comment: @Sajith Nair  only the bottom submit button is supposed to redirect. not the top one.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you don't want to submit your form through post or get. and want to submit another way

```
 <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: all that does is disable all functionality of the form.

Comment: there why you stop redirect and where to stop redirect?

Comment: top submit is an insert into the database. onsubmit="return false;"> fails the 'submit/insert' function. Yeah it stops the redirect alright, but also the rest of the functionality. The bottom submit is the redirect and it works fine.